# Como mudar background do ImageBrush?

Tags: c#, wpf

Segue código **XAML:**

```
<TextBox />
    <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="image_background" Stretch="Fill" TileMode="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" />
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

Segue código **C#:** (O código a seguir, tem um evento `click`, para mudar a imagem do textbox de cor preto)

```
image_background.ImageSource = CreateBitmapSource(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)); // Black Color
```

O que funciona é só no evento `Loaded`:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // aqui consigo mudar a cor
   image_background.ImageSource = CreateBitmapSource(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));
}
```

Alguma solução para mudar a cor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode setar uma cor para o fundo do `TextBox` utilizando a propriedade [`TextBox.Background`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.background(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
textBox.Background = Brushes.Black; // a classe Brushes já tem cores pré definidas
```

Se quer uma imagem no fundo, faça:

```
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("caminho/arquivo.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
textBox.Background = imageBrush;
```

O [`ImageBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx) é para preencher uma área com uma **imagem**. Se não for para esse propósito, não faz muito sentido seu uso.